# Load another window in background; when rendered, close the parent window

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have been trying to load another window in background within a window; parent window acts as a *splash screen* in my case.

```
InitWindow I = null;
    public InitWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        I = this;

        Thread T = new Thread(() =>
        {
            MainWindow M = new MainWindow();
            M.Show();
            M.ContentRendered += M_ContentRendered;
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
            M.Closed += (s, e) => M.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

        }) { IsBackground = true, Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest };

        T.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        T.Start();
    }

    void M_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        I.Close();
    }
```

Everything else works fine but it throws an Invalid Operation Exception at:

```
I.Close();
```

> the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

1) How do I switch/sync thread?

2) Is there a better workaround?

Comment: For an interactive splash screen, I'd rather do the loading and setup in the background and then after it's done, switch the contents of the window...

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek you are suggesting instead of using two windows I should use a single one?

Comment: Yeah, show the contents first, do some loading, then switch the main window contents to what you really want to show. Of course that's good for *interactive* splash screens, if you just have an image, then set the build action to 'Splash Screen' and problem is solved without any magic.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Thanks for your suggestion. I'd definitely try it out perhaps, it'd my last resort. But I'll spend a bit more time to find a workaround to this one.

Comment: I'm not sure, but Window is handled in GUI Thread. You should consider using Dispatcher BeginInvoke Method to manage close event.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [WPF's built-in splash screen support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656886.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed code to:

```
    InitWindow I = null;
    Thread C = null;  

    public InitWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        I = this;
        C = Thread.CurrentThread;  

        Thread T = new Thread(() =>
        {
            MainWindow M = new MainWindow();
            M.Show();
            M.ContentRendered += M_ContentRendered;
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
            M.Closed += (s, e) => M.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();

        }) { IsBackground = true, Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest };

        T.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        T.Start();
    }

    void M_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Making the parent thread background
        C.IsBackground = true; 
        // foreground the current thread
        Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = false;
        // Abort the parent thread
        C.Abort();
    }
```

Works fine as of now, but I don't think it's a reliable solution.